# Как опубликовать свой код на сайте?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Хочу на свой сайт добавить некоторый исходный код типа:

```
def hi(): 
    print('hello')
```

Пару раз в сети видел такое с припиской снизу

> Published with love by github
> Подскажите, пожалуйста, как эта штука по научному называется, и где ее искать, чтобы подключить.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду опубликовать красиво оформленный код, то обернуть в теги `<pre><code>` а потом использовать одну из библиотек для подсветки синтаксиса. Например https://highlightjs.org/

Comment: Да, это именно то, что я искал. А есть такая подсветка синтаксиса от github?

Comment: @JohnBarrow, если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужен стиль подсветки как на Github, если да, то у библиотеки, что скинули выше, есть такой стиль, можете посмотреть [тут](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<pre><code>
def hi():
    print('hello')
</code></pre>
```